# Want to play short voice recordings, with fast switching between them

Tags: audio

I want to output a chosen sound (e.g a singer singing a D, or E, or F note) which I have recorded.  I can change the filetype to whatever is neccessary, e.g mp3 or whatever.  The recording could be 10ms, or longer if that helps.

I want to be able to switch between notes quickly (ideally 1ms delay), is this possible?  I read about using a WTV020-SD Mini but this has a gap of 20ms between tunes sadly.

At the very least I don't want a 20ms noiseless 'gap' as it switches between one note to the next.  If it plays the old noise that would be ok, but ideally i'd like it to be able to switch between the notes in a millisecond or so.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Ideally, the solution would be narrow, to fit in a 10mm radius cylinder, up to 100mm in length, although ideally smaller.

Comment: You're never going to fit an Arduino into those dimensions. Consider using a bare MCU instead.

Comment: The audio files can be on whatever - i'd only have about 10 of them - so not sure if they'd fit on 32KB arduino memory, or could use a microsd or anything else that would help.

Comment: The dimensions are not a huge importance if it doesn't fit, it's fine, just would be ideal if it did.  What is an MCU?  Google didn't help.  Apologies for typo - meant radius not diametre.

Comment: It's the fourth link. And fifth. And sixth.

Comment: OK thanks for that.  Do you have any information on the main topic, i.e not about the size of it?

Comment: Store the sounds interleaved in a SPI flash. Change the index of the byte you output. Since all three sounds are loaded at the same time, there will be only a few microseconds delay maximum.

Comment: Agree on the SPI flash, but no need for interleaved.  An ATtiny25/45/85 is probably sufficient, and has better PWM than an ATmega anyway.